# Showing that there exists a surjective homomorphism from the integers to a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do I show that if $G$ is a cyclic group, say $G=\langle g \rangle$, then there exists a surjective homomorphism from the set of integers to $G$?

Do I start by listing the elements of $G=\langle g \rangle$ as $\lbrace 1, g, g^2, ..., g^{n-1}\rbrace$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f : \mathbb Z \to G$ define by $f(j) = g^j$. Since $G$ is cyclic, $f$ is surjective. $f$ is also a homomorphism since $g^{j+k} = g^j g^k$.

Answer (score 1):

Any finite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$, where $N$ is the order of the cyclic group. Any infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. In the first case, the surjective homomorphism is just the quotient map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. In the second case, the surjective homomorphism is just the identity (isomorphism).

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how? I **just** learned the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: If your cyclic group is finite and generated by $g$, then you just send $g$ to $1\mod N$ in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$. You should convince yourself that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: You should also note that the group operation in $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ is addition, whereas the group operation in your cyclic group is probably written multiplicatively.

Comment: @oxeimon The OP is looking for a surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $G$. I don't think that mentioning $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ here is necessary.

Comment: Okay, I suppose I should have said: consider the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\langle g\rangle$ obtained by sending $n$ to $g^n$. It should be easy to check from the definition of $\langle g\rangle$ that this is surjective.